# react-native init myProject

Tags: ios, react-native

I just started using react-native. I followed the steps in the 'Get Started' section of the documentation. When I execute `react-native init myProject` the project files are created. When I execute the `open ios/myProject.xcodeproj` it takes me to Xcode. When I run the simulator I get the following message on the ios screen. How should I troubleshoot this issue?

> [fatal][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Application myProject has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three possibilities without any code samples.

1. You haven't started the packager : `./node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command ; exit;`
2. You have another RN project's packager running.
3. You have an error in your index.os.js file, maybe provide us a sample of it so we can check.

Comment: I don't have a packager sub-folder in ./node_modules/react-native/.

Comment: Please see code in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b414j30ukcwt7gy/ReactNotes.zip?dl=0

Comment: G Hamaide: Basically, as you suggested it was #2. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can also be the name of your project and the registered component don't match.

You started your project with:

```
react-native init myapp
```

But your index.ios.js says

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Anothername', () => Anothername);
```

Change it to

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => Anothername);
```

And run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please see a related question I had posted and found a solution to
[Solution to another native-react problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632737/xcode-or-native-react-latches-on-to-a-wrong-root-directory-to-search-for-ios-js/35633394#35633394).

In summary, processes running on port 8081 were not terminated when I ended the simulator. This was creating a lot of issues.